# StoryMap c яндекс картами

Tags: яндекс-карты

Может быть кто-то знает или делал что-то подобное? 
Проблема в том что нужно использовать яндекс карты.
или что-то похоже но с яндекс картами.
Пример storymap
https://storymap.knightlab.com/

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, простейший пример боковой панели для API Яндекс.Карт, вероятно это то что вам подойдет:

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/sidebar